# How to check the type of es6 proxy in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I am working with ES6 Proxy. I have created a proxy of an array, now when i check the type of proxy it is giving me as `Object` type.

**Question:**

How can i check if the proxy i have created was for array or object?

**Example:**

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const arrProxy = new Proxy(arr, {});

alert(typeof(arrProxy));
```

**UPDATE (SOLUTION):**
Instead of using `typeof`, we should use `Array.isArray`

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const arrProxy = new Proxy(arr, {});

alert(Array.isArray(arrProxy));
```

Comment: `typeof []` is also 'object', try `Array.isArray(arrProxy)`

Comment: Are you asking how to tell that `arrProxy` is an **array**, or how to tell it's a **proxy**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't tell that a proxy is a proxy. That's part of the point of them, they provide a facade (one you can't detect) around another object.

As far as code looking at your `arrProxy` can tell, it's an array:

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

const arrProxy = new Proxy(arr, {});

console.log(Array.isArray(arrProxy)); // true
```

Separately: [`typeof`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-typeof-operator) is **very** general, it gives you `"object"` for a huge range of things: Anything that's of an object (not primitive) type (including `null`). So `typeof new Map()`, `typeof new Set()`, `typeof null`, `typeof document` (on browsers), etc., will all give you `"object"`. (Also note that `typeof` is an operator, not a function; no need for the `()` in your code sample.)

Answer (score 2):

As other answers suggest, you cannot tell if something is a proxy.

So you might need to implement it yourself.

Here is an example from: https://exploringjs.com/deep-js/ch_proxies.html#transparent-virtualization-and-handler-encapsulation

```
const proxies = new WeakSet();

export function createProxy(obj) {
  const handler = {};
  const proxy = new Proxy(obj, handler);
  proxies.add(proxy);
  return proxy;
}

export function isProxy(obj) {
  return proxies.has(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also one way to do this using [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
if (arrProxy instanceof Array) {
   console.log('This is an array!');
}
```

Comment: That will fail for any array you receive from another *realm*. Which is why we have `Array.isArray`.

Comment: What do you mean by `another realm` here?

Comment: @JoharZaman - A [realm](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-code-realms) *"...consists of a set of intrinsic objects, an ECMAScript global environment, all of the ECMAScript code that is loaded within the scope of that global environment, and other associated state and resources."* So for instance, if you have a page with an iframe in it, the page and the iframe are separate realms; if you pass an array from one to the other, `instanceof` won't work. Similarly if one window opens another, if you pass data between them, that data is crossing realms.

Comment: @marsibarsi There is a problem with `instanceof`. When i am using `arrProxy instanceof Object` it still gives me true.

Comment: `__proto__` of `Array` is `Object` that is why `arrProxy instanceof Object` is also `true`